# How to toggle search results displayed in a li with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've been searching methods to toggle a list that gets displayed when an user searches something in my app. What I want to do is have my search results hide whenever the search bar is closed. What would be the best way to do this? I believe I should do this with angular somehow but I'm out of ideas on how to do it. I tried the following jquery without success:

```
$("input").click(function(){
    $("ul").toggle();
});
```

My codepen for this is: http://codepen.io/Feners4/pen/ZGZORX

Comment: You can use [ngBlur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) , and reset your search result inside your onBlur method.
e.g. 
ng-blur='clearResult()'

$scope.clearResult = function() {
    $scope.searchTxt == "";
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as suggested by [Rishi-Vedpathak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3289313/rishi-vedpathak) add ng-blur as follows :

```
    input(type='text' ng-model='searchTxt' ng-change='autoComplete()' ng-blur='searchTxt=""')
--or--
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchTxt" ng-change="autoComplete()" ng-blur="searchTxt=''"/>
```

set ng-show on the  tag as :

```
ul(ng-show='searchTxt && searchTxt!=""')
--or--
<ul ng-show="searchTxt && searchTxt!=''">
```

Comment: Thank you for making this method clear to me. It worked. Simple and effective.

Comment: Mind explaining a bit what is happening on ```ul(ng-show='searchTxt && searchTxt!=""')``` ?

Comment: @feners : sorry for the confusion "or" just specifies the syntax difference. The one you asked is a HTML(Jade) syntax specified in the codepen link in the question.

Answer (score 0):

On search results list `<div>` or `<ul>` add `ng-show="searchResults"` or `ng-show="isSearchResults()"`.

```
<div ng-show="isSearchResults()"></div>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.isSearchResults = function() {
return $scope.searchResults.length !== 0;
}
```